# ios - hide/unhide a view in a viewcontroller from another uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I have a UItableview, and I have a ViewController.  In my ViewController I have 3 Views (View1, View2, View3).

I want to decide which one of the views to show according to the cell chosen in the UItableview.

so I made 3 cells in the uitableview, and made in each of them a button, and i declared that by pressing button1, ==> view1.hidden = no , view2.hidden = yes  ,and Etc...

BUT it doesnt work becuase my Views are in the viewcontroller and this code i wrote is in the UItableview. so it didnt understand about which "Views" Im talking about.

So the problem is that the buttons and the views are in different places, buttons are in the UItableview and the Views are in the ViewController, And I want to control the Views using the buttons.

How can i do that ???

Help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your code? Is the tableview another view in your uiviewcontroller or is it a seperate tableviewcontroller?

Comment: I'm using this... https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu

Comment: "so it didnt understand about which "Views" Im talking about." does it not compile?

Comment: because the views are in the viewcontroller.h ,but the view1.hidden = NO, is in the UItableview.m

Answer (score 2):

If your `UITableView` is a member/property of your view controller, then you would just make your view controller conform to the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol.  That protocol defines the method `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` which is called after a cell/row is selected.  From within there, you can inspect the `indexPath` to determine which cell/row it was.  Then, based on that knowledge, you can easily work on which ever child view you are interested in.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIView *theView;
    switch(indexPath.row) {
        case 0: // the first row selected
            theView = view1;
            break;
        case 1: // the second row selected
            theView = view2;
            break;
        // etc.
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (theView != nil) {
        // do work
    }
}
```

Comment: okay maybe I'm doing it all wrong, I'm using this code... https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu/tree/master/Demos/MFSideMenuDemoStoryboard/MFSideMenuDemoStoryboard   So I want to rename each cell in the "SideMenuViewController.m" and make each one of them show a specific UIView in the "DemoViewController.m". any help with that ?

Comment: So my suggestion does not apply to your situation.

You are going to need to do something more complicated as you are attempting to communicate between various view controllers. You have a few options, but here are two:

(1) create a delegate protocol for communication between the menu and the center view controller. The center view controller can then do what it needs to communicate with its children.
(2) publish and subscribe to various notifications where you put the desired payload in the `userInfo` dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nsnotification center:

tableviewcontroller.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    switch(indexPath.row) {
        case 0: // the first row selected
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"viewShowChange" object:@"view0"];
            break;
        case 1: // the second row selected
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"viewShowChange" object:@"view1"];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Your view controller with the hidden views:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(viewShowChanged:) name:@"viewShowChanged" object:nil];
}


- (void)viewShowChanged:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSString *recieveObj = [notification object];
    if([recieveObj isEqualTo:@"view0]) self.view0.hidden = NO;
    else if([recieveObj isEqualTo:@"view1"]) self.view1.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: i get this errors from the demoviewcontroller.m ===>   No visible [at]interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'isEqualTo:'

and…

Property 'view0' not found on object of type 'ViewControllerSlider *'; did you mean 'view'?

and…

No visible [at]interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'isEqualTo:'

and…

Property 'view1' not found on object of type 'ViewControllerSlider *'; did you mean 'view'?

Comment: i replaced the @ sign with [at], twice in my last comment because the site didnt let me comment with too many @'s